# Design components for Catalyst framework

Tags: perl, catalyst

After three years spent using Angular I decided to go back to one of my first loves, Perl (99% back-end). More than that, I want to create my first public website using the Catalyst Framework.

Is there any design components package available for Catalyst Framework? Something similar to Angular Material.

Any hint or suggestion is appreciated.

KI

Comment: No, there is not. Catalyst is the pure backend, and the concept of components that you know from Angular is not the same in most backend MVC frameworks. You have modules like Form Fu or Form Builder that do form processing for you, but you still have to do the other templates and styling yourself. A View in Catalyst is not a template, but the thing rendering a template, or converting to JSON or XML or sending an email... you get the idea. Models should hold all the logic, so there might be models talking to APIs, and Controllers should only do the dispatching.

Comment: (Your question is asking for software recommendations, so it's off-topic. I'm voting to close.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have experience working on Angular, you can take advantage of it, and build your [SPA interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) with:

- Angular at the frontend
- Perl (with your favorite framework, like Mojolicious, Catalyst, Dancer2, ...) at the backend (RESTful web service).